# Combining multiple .csv files using pandas and keeping the original structure

Tags: python, pandas, csv, glob

I have around 60 .csv files which i would like to combine in pandas. So far i've used this:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

total_files = glob.glob("something*.csv") 

data = [] 
for csv in total_files:
    list = pd.read_csv(csv, encoding="utf-8", sep='delimiter', engine='python')
    data.append(list)

biggerlist = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True) 
biggerlist.to_csv("output.csv")
```

This works somewhat, only the files I would like to combine all have the same structure of 15 columns with the same headers. When I use this code, only one column is filled with info of the entire row, and every column name is add-up of all column names (e.g. SEARCH_ROW, DATE, TEXT, etc.).

How can I combine these csv files, while keeping the same structure of the original files?

Edit:

So perhaps I should be a bit more specific regarding my data. This is a snapshot of one of the .csv files i'm using:

[As you can see it is just newspaper-data, where the last column is 'TEXT', which isn't shown completely when you open the file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxVQR.jpg)

[This is a part of how it looks when i have combined the data using my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DH5q.jpg)

Apart, i can read any of these .csv files no problem using

```
data = pd.read_csv("something.csv",encoding="utf-8", sep='delimiter', engine='python')
```

Comment: Remove `sep='delimiter'` because that implies that you use the string 'delimiter' to separate your columns (I assume that isn't the case), so remove it to let pandas automatically sniff it out.

Comment: @coldspeed thanks for the quick response. i've tried this, only then i get the error 'ParserError: unexpected end of data' when i try to read my files

Comment: Add an `errors='ignore'`?

Comment: If that still doesn't work, I recommend isolating the lines from your CSV that are erroring out and/or pasting some of your data here in your question.

Comment: i've added ignore_errors=True, and then 'EOL while scanning string literal' pops up

Comment: I see... please see my comment just above and see if you can edit your question to provide a [mcve] that helps us reproduce your issue.

Comment: @coldspeed, again, thanks for the quick reply. I could add the line which errors out, but it would just be a blob of text (as i can't find what's exactly wrong with it). Would that be helpful in any way?

Comment: Sounds like you might have commas within those large text values throwing off columns. Consider saving CSVs with quotes around string fields.

Comment: agree with coldspeed, this is really hard to diagnose without a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

The problem was the amount of comma's in the text part of my .csv files. So after removing all comma's (just using search/replace), I used:

```
import pandas
import glob

filenames = glob.glob("something*.csv")
df = pandas.DataFrame()
for filename in filenames:
df = df.append(pandas.read_csv(filename, encoding="utf-8", sep=";"))
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Can you please fix indentation in your code? Also, can you explain why `df.append` is better than the `pd.concat` method?